# Leaflet 1.0 how to extend getPixelBounds?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to extend the view to render more tiles because my map is 3D rotated on the X axis.
This piece of code works well in version < 1:

```
var getPxBounds = map.getPixelBounds;
map.getPixelBounds = function() {
   var bounds = getPxBounds.call(this);
   // ... extend the bounds
   var value = 250;
   bounds.min.x = bounds.min.x - value;
   bounds.min.y = bounds.min.y - value;
   bounds.max.x = bounds.max.x + value;
   bounds.max.y = bounds.max.y + value;
   return bounds;
};
```

Could you please help me how to do the same in version 1.0.0-b1?
Here is two jsbins to reproduce the problem:

[jsBin for leaflet version 0.7.5](http://jsbin.com/pubanovuqi/edit?js,output)

[jsBin for leaflet version 1.0.0-b1](http://jsbin.com/fuwicuxobe/edit?js,output)

**UPDATE**
Solution is here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3838

Comment: The main reason it's not working on master is that map.getPixelBounds is not called when zooming and panning in your example, just put a console.log in it and I never see it triggered. I have no time at the moment to look deeper but might sometimes afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the leaflet community solved my problem. The original question is updated with the solution.